# How do I rebuild the Minecraft shim layer?

Tags: pi-4, java, minecraft, 64-bit

I'm running a Minecraft server off a RPi4 8gb, but the raspian OSs is 32 bit, limiting the memory I can allocate to the server. There is a beta 64 bit os, but on of the things missing is Minecraft's shim layer. Is this necessary to run a Minecraft server? If so, how do I rebuild it?